# Can't align a fixed header with the content div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout where the header is fixed and the middle header div is aligned with the content div.

I got two issues:

1. There is a small offset that I can't fix.
2. The border-top of `content-wrapper` is not visible, why?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxZJ3/3/

*Offset and no border-top:*

[image: Offset in Google Chrome]

Comment: where is the small offset? and I also see a dashed top border on the `content-wrapper`.

Comment: Where is the offset? Between your header and content area? I can see the border from your `content-wrapper` just fine. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I had included the wrong CSS. Please check the new fiddler uri (update 3). I've also included a screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset is due to you setting a `padding: 5px` on a `width: 100%`.

The reason you can't see the border-top is because of the `border-bottom` on the `#header`, which gives it an extra `1px` of height, for a total of `61px`. I would decrease the `height` to `59px`, thereby yielding a total height of `60px`.

Edit: Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxZJ3/16/)

Comment: Isn't `padding` inside an element, so that it should work with 100% width?

Comment: Correct. This `padding: 5px` offsets the Menu div, take that out and they align just fine. This is because it pads it an extra 5px left and right, even with width: 100%. Also, why do you have `margin: 0px auto` then `margin-top: 55px`, why not just have `margin: 55px auto`?

Comment: I removed that extra margin. I added it since I didn't see the top border. Check the updated fiddler.

Comment: The width is thought of as the width of the content, and then padding is added to that. So, in this case, you're adding 5px to an already 100% width-sized element, which is causing it to grow beyond the bounds of 100% (and, thereby, offset your alignment)

Comment: @jgauffin I updated my answer to reflect your corrected fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix is to replace `width: 100%;` with `right:0; left: 0;`: http://jsfiddle.net/sxZJ3/14/

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the padding there is no issue, The main content is floating directly below the header. If you want to decrease this gap you could use padding or a variety of other options. Margin or even use the single border for both elements inline.

Could also try some positioning tricks. Div inside a container with a postition:relative and a fixed-height. Then on the div position:absolute and then margins and padding as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a build more along these lines where you remove the body margin and allow the content-wrapper to be the sole margin pushing down the content.  Also the padding within the header is causing the #menu to be offset by 5px within the header element.  http://jsfiddle.net/sxZJ3/12/